# Use zone.js to detect current execution context from anywhere?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, monkeypatching

With [zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js) is it possible to determine the current execution context from **anywhere**? Ie., if a zone-bound function calls another function which calls `setTimeout(myFn)` can I determine the current execution context from within `myFn()`? If so, please provide a simple example of how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you `fork()` a **zone**, accessing the `zone` object within that **zone**'s context will always return the forked `zone`.

#### The following experiment demonstrates this behavior:

```
var b = function() { console.log('-->',zone) }; 
var a = function() { setTimeout(b,5); }; 
zone.fork().run(function() { zone.x = 'hi'; a(); }); 
setTimeout(function() { console.log('==>', zone); }, 1);
setTimeout(function() { console.log('==>', zone); }, 10);
```

#### Here's what happens when you paste it into the console:

[image]