# Angular 2 - Substitute for $scope.$apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-scope, angular

`$scope.$apply` will no longer be part of Angular 2. Then how do we let Angular know to update the DOM if any of the bound properties have been changed outside the regular angular execution context?

Taken from [a blog post by Minko Gechev](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/04/06/angular2-first-impressions#no-more-scopeapply):

> **No more $scope.$apply**
>
> But how then AngularJS knows that anything outside it’s execution context has taken a place? Lets think where the changes might come from:
>
> - setTimeout
> - setInterval
> - prompt (yeah, there are people who still use it…)
> - XMLHttpRequest
> - WebSockets
> - …

For which the answer is:

[image]

I understand that patching the browser built-in javascript functions to notify of any changes to Angular is something that can be done in a relatively safe manner (without introducing subtle bugs) and would be very convenient for the developer. But what about third party APIs (such as `jQuery.fadeIn`) or if the browser exposes some new asynchronous API which isn't covered? What's the substitute for old `$scope.$apply`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the library that does all this monkey patching is [zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js).

`jQuery.fadeIn` calls `setInterval`, `setInterval` is monkey patched, as long as you called `jQuery.fadeIn` within a `zone.run`.

`zone.fork` and `zone.run` kind of replace `$scope.$apply`, but it's different because it detects itself when asynchronous things have finished, whereas you have to call `$scope.$apply` *manually* when you know things have finished. 
See also this question+answer: [Use zone.js to detect current execution context from anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164756/use-zone-js-to-detect-current-execution-context-from-anywhere)

> if the browser exposes some new asynchronous API which isn't covered?

I guess they will patch that too.

**If everything else fails**, you can still call `zone.afterTask()` manually.
I guess that's what you were looking for :)

Comment: I'm seeing some internal google stuff like https://github.com/sararob/angular2base/blob/master/src/firebasepipe.ts using a ChangeDetectorRef instead - anybody know if that is the new hotness and the zone.afterTask() method is deprecated? Or what the relationship is there?

Comment: zone.afterTask() doesn't do anything for me at all. Is there something I need to do to hook that up to check for changes to ng2 views?

Comment: For anyone looking for how to include Zone in your Angular 2 project, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381680/angular-2-change-detection and this http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/3-way-data-binding

Comment: Further to the above, an implementation of zone implementation in ES5 can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287164/angular-2-0-beta-es5-ui-not-updating-via-custom-event

Answer (score 26):

1. import `NgZone` from core
2. `private zone: NgZone` in your constructor
3. `this.zone.run(() => {});` where you would normally `scope.$apply`

or

1. `ChangeDetectorRef`
2. `private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef`
3. `chRef.detectChanges();`

Comment: This is perfect solution!...
Thanks

Comment: When i use second one i am getting this.chRef as undefined

Comment: by `await async` function only the first solution worked for me