# Angular 2 How to get Angular to detect changes made outside Angular?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-changedetection

I am trying to create a simple example project to test the angular 2 change detection mechanism: I create a pure javascript object in script tags on the main index page. it contains the following:

```
        var Tryout = {};
        Tryout.text = "Original text here";
        Tryout.printme = function(){
            console.log(Tryout.text);
        }
        Tryout.changeme = function(){
            Tryout.text = "Change was made";
        }
```

One function to console log it, and one to change the text property.

Now in Angular 2 the code looks like this:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core"

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>{{TryoutRef.text}}</h1>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="TryoutRef.text">
        <button (click)="consoleLogMe()">Console Log</button>
        <button (click)="changeMe()">Change me inside</button>
    `
})

export class MyApp{

    TryoutRef:any = Tryout;
    constructor(){
    }
    changeMe(){
        this.TryoutRef.changeme();
    }
    consoleLogMe(){
        console.log(this.TryoutRef.text);
    }

}
declare var Tryout:string;
```

What I am trying to do is this:
When I call the function Tryout.printme() normally with onclick (Completely outside of angular) I want angular to detect the change and update the screen.

I succeeded to this point: When I call Tryout.printme() from the component (the changeme() function is calling Tryout.printme()), Angular detects the change and updates the UI which is fine. Also, when I change from outside angular and I call consoleLogMe() from Angular it is logging the changed text and updates the UI.

I guess I need to execute Tryout.changeme() in the same Zone that Angular is running in somehow. Any ideas? I have a big project which is done in pure javascript/jquery, and now I slowly need to rewrite the handlebar templates to angular2 components without touching the model (yet). For that I need to force the model to execute in the same zone as angular.

*If I wanted to do something like this in Angular 1 I would just $scope.$apply it would work.*

**Here is a gif from the example:**

[image]

Comment: Why is `Tryout` type `string` in the component file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by exporting `NgZone` inside your Angular app.
Usually, you should do all things inside Angular, but if you really want to execute your logic out of Angular, you need to get the right `zone`, as you have said.

This trick is abusing Angular's dependency injection and hooking the injected `zone` on `window` object, as [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5979) shows. Declaring a dependency on `NgZone`, and assigning it to `window.zoneImpl` for exporting.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgZone} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(zone: NgZone) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    window.app = this
    window.zoneImpl = zone
  }
}
```

After Angular bootstrapping, you should have a `zoneImpl` global variable. You can use the `run` method to kick Angular off.

`zoneImpl.run(() => window.app.name = "new name!")`

[Live demo.](https://plnkr.co/edit/rH73slX6xonZXOnSjJxo?p=preview)

Comment: Another fast and ugly hack is, after bootstrapping, use `setTimeout` to make Angular aware of your code. `NgZone` has patched this global function.

Comment: Could you please check the plunkr (message": "Preview has expired or project does not exist.") its gone.

Comment: A word of warning: make sure to (as demonstrated above) name your window.zoneImpl variable something *other* than window.zone. Apparently window.zone is used by Angular and if you write to it, it'll screw things up.

Comment: See also [Günter's alternative approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36832108/215945): set up an event listener inside Angular (hence inside the Angular zone). Then fire that event whenever you make changes outside the Angular zone.

Comment: I just inject NgZone into all my components and wrap all external callbacks into `ngZone.run(() => { doSomething(); });`.