# Reacting to changes made outside of Angular2

Tags: data-binding, angular, angular2-changedetection

I've got a non-angular page made with fairly basic JS, and thought it'd be a splendid idea to try and add learn some Angular2 and use it for some new functionality.

My plan was that I'd bind an Angular2 component to an object that is being updated by the old code, and I'd use Angular2 magic to update a chunk of UI.

The problem is I cant convince Angular2 to react to any changes made in the outside JS. What the trick to doing that? Attempts at googling the problem lead to in depth explanations of Angular2's change detection process, which hasn't been helpful so far. Is this just an awful idea?

I found a random Angular2 jsfiddle and hacked it up to show the problem. Strings are added to 'window.names', but you dont see them until one is added from the angular side: https://jsfiddle.net/byfo3jg3/ . The code follows:

```
var names = ['Joe'];

setTimeout(function() {
  names.push("Frank");
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  names.push("Sterve");
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
  names.push("Garfield");
}, 3000);

(function() {
  var HelloApp,
        ListThing;

    ListThing = ng
        .Component({
            selector: 'list-thing',
            template: '<ul><li *ng-for="#name of names">{{name}}</li></ul>',
            directives: [ng.NgFor]
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function() {
                this.names = window.names;

        setTimeout(function() {
                    this.names.push("Oh hai");
                }.bind(this), 10000);
            }
        });

    HelloApp = ng
        .Component({
            selector: 'hello-app',
            template: '<list-thing></list-thing>',
            directives: [ListThing]
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function() {}
        });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        ng.bootstrap(HelloApp);
    });
}());
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that unless you Absolutely have to! Otherwise look into Observables and subscribe to changes on that Array in your component, updating the components array when changes come in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the NgZone to window object and then call run function of the zone.

Please refer to [Angular 2 How to get Angular to detect changes made outside Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381680/angular-2-change-detection) SO Question

Comment: While I decided to go follow Mark's advice and basically try to convert more of my app into Angular2 instead of sidestepping around it, I think this was the first answer that pointed at what appears to be the "Angular" way to do what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`names` should be component property to work inside of template:

```
constructor(){this.names = window.names}
```

Changes to `window.names` will not be detected by angular, so you have few options: poll names using `setInterval(()=>{this.names = window.names}, 1000)` or expose global callback:

```
constructor(zone:NgZone) 
{
   window.notify = ()=> {
        zone.run(()=> { 
                this.names = window.names;
        });
   }
 }
```

and call it from plain js `window.notify()` or use other methods to invoke change detection.

Comment: The `notify()` idea won't work because you would be calling `notify()` from outside the Angular zone, so change detection won't run.  Test fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sv2xv7x0/2/

Comment: Then you could fairly easy add `zone.run` to notify method.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this just an awful idea?

Yes.

Angular's automatic change detection system assumes that changes to data (that you want your components to display) are happening inside an event handler that is monkey-patched by Zone.js.  Because then Angular's change detection will execute when such an event handler fires (well, technically, it will execute after the event handler finishes).

If you want a component view to automatically update, you have to change the bound data inside Angular – inside the Angular zone.  As @Jigar answered, you can modify your code to call `angularZone.run(_ => // make changes here)`, but if you have to do that, you might as well move the code that manages and manipulates the data into a service (or a component, if the logic is minimal).

See also [Günter's alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36832108/215945): set up an event listener inside Angular (hence inside the Angular zone).  Then fire that event whenever you make changes outside the Angular zone.