# ionic , angular - global variable inside index.html to be called by other ts pages

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

How it's possible to component (ts file) get access to a variable inside index.html? exemple:

inside: index.html
    
    `<javascript>
       var myVar = "test";
    </javascript>`

how to get this variable "myVar" to be used inside a component page

to be used for example on the component html like {{myVar}}

Comment: It is not possible. that piece of JS might be in a totally different bundle than the script-code in your components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the ts file, you can declare it like this :

```
//Other imports
declare var myVar: any;

@Component({
selector: 'my-component',
templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})

export class MyComponent {
  my_javascript_variable = myVar;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. works fine. Are there any listerner to await changes for this variable ?

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828856/angular2-watch-an-external-variable-outside-of-angular. They have used it like window.myVar, instead of declaring it into the component.