# How to detect window object change in Angular 5 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to load an Angular 5 application inside an existing jQuery based website. I have a requirement to detect change in a variable of the window object, and based on the change, I need to update the views in the Angular component.

I am able to read the window object when I do some action. Is it possible to detect window object change inside Angular component?

I have not yet started.

Comment: how do you load angular app into juqery? iframe?

Comment: I think you can join the answers in these two different posts to make it work: [liste variable change in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript) and [trigger angular variable change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828856/angular2-watch-an-external-variable-outside-of-angular)