# How to force UI "refresh" on nativescript (typescript) with Observables throught http requests?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, nativescript

I'm using a TabView component with template syntax to iterate over it and add items inside (using an observable collection and async pipe). My items come from a http request.

My home.component.tns.html as follows:

```
<ActionBar title="Angular 2 Seed Advanced (nativescript)">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
  <TabView selectedIndex="0" selectedColor="#FF0000">
    <template ngFor let-tab [ngForOf]="tabs | async">
      <StackLayout *tabItem="tab">
          <Label text="tab item"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
    </template>
  </TabView>

  <Button text="call something" (tap)="emptymethod()"></Button>

</StackLayout>
```

...and my home.component.ts:

```
...
    export class HomeComponent{

        public tabs: Observable<any[]>;

        constructor(private _menuService: MenuService) {

            this._menuService.getMenu()
                .map((menus) => {
                    let result: Array<any> = [];

                    if (menus) {
                        menus.forEach(menu => {
                            result.push({ 'title': menu.title });
                        });
                    }
                    return result;
                })
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.tabs = Observable.of<any[]>(data);
                },
                error => error => this._log.debug(error));
        }

        emptymethod() {
            this._log.debug('HomeComponent - nada invoked');
        }

        ngOnInit() {

        }
    ...
```

When the interface is renderized, the TabView menu does not appears, but when i click over *call something* button and *emptymethod* is called the items inside the TabView appears, in other words, after the "refresh" that component appears...

This should not happens automatically?

Answer (score 14):

I had couple of situations with nativescript where the UI wont refresh (the zone will not trigger a UI refresh or something) and the easiest way to do it is to force the code to run into the zone. Here is small example

```
export class TestClass {
   constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {
   }
   someOperation(){
     this._ngZone.run(() => {
       //Do whatever you want here
     })
   }
}
```

I know this is not the best solution but thats the cleanest workaround currently I think

Here is another question that I asked months ago related to this: [Angular 2 How to get Angular to detect changes made outside Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381680/angular-2-how-to-get-angular-to-detect-changes-made-outside-angular)

Comment: thanks dude, it worked perfect for me, it may not be the optimal solution, but it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with how async operations and change detection is being handled in nativescript-angular when third party plugins are involved.

The current suggestion is to wrap all async notify calls within a zoned callback function.

The following video explains the issue and solution. Hope this helps.
http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/videos/2016/06/13/zoned-callbacks.html

More details on a corresponding feature request in Nativescript is present here.
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2229

Answer (score 0):

I would guess because the change detection is not being triggered when the `next` block in the subscribe is called so the change to `this.tabs` is not detected until changed detection triggered by the button press.

You should be able to simplify your Observable and just do:

```
        this.tabs = this._menuService.getMenu()
            //Convert the Array into a flattened Observable
            .flatMap((menus) => menus ? menus.map(({title}) => {title}) : []);
```

Which will flatten the array into an Observable implicitly for your `ngFor` block.

Comment: Is **flatMap** a function from Observables? I'm receiving a message _flatMap in not a function_ ...or should i return a array from **getMenu** and not a Observable?

Comment: Yes `flatMap` is a function on `Observable`, it is an alias for `mergeMap`. You may need to import it see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#installation-and-usage)