# Angular 2.0 (Beta, ES5) UI not updating via custom event

Tags: angular, jquery-events

I am having an issues with Angular 2.0.0-beta.2

I have two components loaded separately into a page and communicate is performed between the Angular 2 components and the 'container' website, these events are performed via jQuery's .trigger() and .on().

The idea of this is these components can be integrated into an external website and a predefined set of events can be used to interact between one another.

The issue I am having with angular2 however is that the binding is not updating the UI immediately if a change is made as the result of an event, see the Plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/VReV7dpx2dYjtDSg9iA4?p=preview

```
<button (click)="toggle()">Click Me to Toggle</button>
```

If you click 'Click me to Toggle', this updates the internal 'initialHide' and shows the hidden div instantly. If you click 'Click me for ShowHide' it fires an event from ComponentOne, which is picked up by ComponentTwo. It updates 'initialHide' but does not update the UI instantly. If you then click 'Click me for Event' it then picks up that an internal property has changed and updates the UI.

So, my question is - why is this? Is it the context in which the 'initialHide' property is being updated? I first thought it may be an error in the event, but you can see from the console logs that the event is firing just fine and updating the initialHide property, the UI does not pick up the binding however.

Is there a way I can force this? Or a mechanism I can use that will update the bindings automatically when invoked via an event from an external source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by injecting NgZone into the constructor. I then execute the event code in zone.run()

https://plnkr.co/edit/VReV7dpx2dYjtDSg9iA4?p=preview

```
constructor : [ng.core.NgZone, function (zone) { ... }
this.updateComp = function() { zone.run() { ... } );
```

Comment: If anybody has a better solution to this however, I would be happy to hear it. I am still new to Angular 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (though in an Ajax callback). I updated `zone.js` to the latest from https://github.com/angular/zone.js/tree/master/dist and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `on()` but instead Angulars mechanisms to register event handlers than you don't have issues with code running outside Angulars zone and updating model values not initiating a change detection cycle.

You can use

```
ng.core
  .Component({ 
      ..., 
      host: {'(window:some-event)':'someFunction($event)'},
  })
```

and when `someFunction()` is called and it udates model values, Angulars change detection will recognize it.